# Triggering animation in character OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I've been stuck on this for hours.

I have a character whose animations are based in mecanim to transition based on the `bool` variable `ShivaEnter`. One invisible cube is set to change the `bool` value from `false` to `true` and vice-versa `OnTriggerEnter`.

The code is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PontyAnimations : MonoBehaviour {

  //[SerializeField]
  private Animator animator;
  //private GameObject ponty;
  //private GameObject ponty;

  void Awake () {
    animator = GetComponent <Animator>();
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
      animator.SetBool ("ShivaEnter", true);
    }
  }

  void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
      animator.SetBool ("ShivaEnter", false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does exactly the code do? Probably does not trigger the animation, but better to say that explicitly. Is the `if` statement ever triggered?

Comment: The if statement is not triggered. There is no change in animation occurring.

Comment: Have you enabled isTrigger at your collider?

Comment: If you never entered the `if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") { ...}` (did we meant the same thing?), then the problem lies in collision detection rather than in animation.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code as following and edited the transitions to be more sudden! It worked.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class boxponty : MonoBehaviour {

  public bool ShivaEnter;
  private GameObject player;
  private Animator anim;
  private AudioClip pontysound;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other){
    anim.SetBool ("ShivaEnter", true);
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
  }

  void OnTriggerExit (Collider other){
    anim.SetBool ("ShivaEnter", false);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to change Start to Update. It only gets slower this way.